# bootstrap mixin globally on symfony encore

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, webpack-encore, symfony5

I started a small symfony project in which i load bootstrap on app.css.
On app.css i also have another include "navigation.scss" on which i use bootstrap mixing and its included in base layout template.
The problem is that if i create a another entrypoint in webpack.config.js, add the css file in a second template, which extends the layout, bootstrap will work but i cannot access mixin functions from bootstrap and the only solution is to also import bootstrap in that css file, but then i have two bootstrap libraries in both css files which will override eachother. How can i make the bootstrap, toghether with mixin, available globally so it will onyl be imported once.

webpack.config.js

```
    * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('homepage', './assets/js/front/homepage.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

app.css

```
// Required
@import "~bootstrap";
@import './helper/variables';
@import 'front/includes/navigation';
```

base_layout

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>{% block title %}Test Application{% endblock %}</title>
      {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
```

second page css

```
@import "~bootstrap";
.hero-banner__wrapper {
  min-height: 700px;
  background-size:cover;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(200, 6, 81, 0.6), rgba(44,13,72,10.6));
  &.menu-active {
    background: rgba(44,13,72,1);
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {

}
```

second page template

```
    {% extends 'front_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('homepage') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block hero %}
    <div class="hero-banner__wrapper" style="background-image: url({{ asset('build/img/hero_img.jpg') }})">

    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('homepage') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are importing in the wrong order. This structure should fit with your case.

app.scss

```
// Required
@import "~bootstrap";
@import './helper/variables';
@import 'front/includes/navigation';

// OTHER THIRD PARTY CSS
```

page1.scss

```
@import "./app.scss";

// CUSTOM SCSS
```

page2.scss

```
@import "./app.scss";

// CUSTOM SCSS
```

This way, you can load the `app.scss` file in your `layout.html.twig`, and just override it (define stylesheets block without call `parent()`) if you need in `page1.html.twig` with `page1.scss` which reload everything in `app.scss` but then you have variables, mixins, and not everything twice.

---

**EDIT**

To reply to your comment, there is few way to structure your project.

**First way**

Make a `main.scss` which contains all import (bootstrap, ...) and global stuff such as navbar, footer, sidebar...
Make for each page a SCSS file.
On each page, load `main.scss` then `page1.scss`.

Resume: At least 2 HTTP Requests, reusable `main.scss` but `page1.scss` doesn't contains any mixins.

**Second way**

Make a `main.scss` which contains all import (bootstrap, ...) and global stuff such as navbar, footer, sidebar...
Make for each page a SCSS file and import `main.scss`.
On each page, load only `page1.scss`.

Resume: 1 HTTP Request (better if you have too much SCSS file), you can have mixins, but you will have `bootstrap` in each SCSS file.

**Third way**

When you open `bootstrap.scss` you can see every import that it does. So you can see that you can only add those lines into your SCSS file to access to Bootstrap's mixins.

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

Comment: I tried your solution and the file size of page2 will be the sum of app.scss + page2.scss.
On my version, i can use, i think all bootsrap features, on page2.scss without actually inporting bootstrap again  (app.scss imports bootstrap) and the page2.scss size is nomal (what ever css is in it).
Is there a way to use the Bootstrap mixin on other pages as long as those individual pages are not imported in app.scss (where they in the scope on app.scss and they can use mixin, but that will make the page2.scss global too)

Comment: I just updated my post, have a look and tell me if it solve your problem